# Netsuite: customizing bulk process screen

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am wondering if there is a way to customize the salesorder manager form [/app/accounting/transactions/salesordermanager.nl?type=fulfill&whence=](https://netsuite.com/app/accounting/transactions/salesordermanager.nl?type=fulfill&whence=)
We need to add a custom field that is to be populate for the fulfillment (it is used during the one by one process, it is also needed during the bulk process)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you can customize this page but for your use case, there is a Set Fields tab under the filters. You can choose your custom field in the tab then assign the value.

Comment: you did not answered to question :) , but you solved my issue, Thanks. I will mark the question as answered anyway